# Chained Payments / direct checkout combo

Tags: php, paypal

I want to be able to have people pay directly on my website.  I'd like to be able to chain payments to "take a cut", which I understand is possible with Adaptive Payments, but from what I read it seems that Adaptive Payments does not support checkout directly on my page.  Can paying more than one payee (as part of a single transaction) be done while keeping the user on the page?  If so, which API?  I'm running PHP 5.5.

Comment: My apologies, kinda new here... this was flagged as too broad by several of you so I've edited it to be more concise and will ask the rest as a separate question.

Comment: Unfortunately this is still rather vague, though perhaps someone quite familiar with the topics will see a way to answer it.

Comment: I've edited it again in an attempt to make it more concise.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Chained payments are part of the PayPal Adaptive Payments program using the PayPal Hosted Page, which means that your buyers will always be on the PayPal Page. The only way that you can possibly make it appear that your customers are staying on your webpage is through embedded pages:

[Adaptive Payments Guide, Scroll Down to the section on Embedded Payments](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/)

From the PayPal Developer site, here is the information on Embedded Payments:

An embedded payment is a payment that initiates a visual presentation of the Adaptive Payments payment flow in which the sender appears to never leave your checkout or payment page. Embedded payments make it easier for a sender to make a payment because PayPal may allow the sender to bypass the PayPal login step.